# Liquid layout line height in percent equal to another height also in percent

Tags: css

Inside a liquid css layout i have this code:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="absolute_small_column"><p>Absolut small calumn title</p></div>
</div>


.absolute_small_column {
position:absolute;
height:15%;
top:85%;
width:100%;
z-index:2000;
}

.absolute_small_column p {
**line-height:100%;** HOW CAN I MAKE THE LINE HEIGHT OF MY P TO FIT THE 15% HEIGHT OF THE DIV?
color:#FFF;
font-weight:700;
margin:0;
padding:0
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in CSS. The best you can do is to specify a line height and set `bottom: 0` instead of `top: 85%; height: 15%`.